# How on write a query with combination condition AND/OR in Where Clause?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, where-clause

```
var query = from uM in db.aspnet_Memberships
                    join uD in db.UserDetails
                    on uM.UserId equals uD.UserId
                    join jL in db.JobLists
                    on uM.UserId equals jL.UserId
                    where (u.UserName == User.Identity.Name or jL.JobId==0)
```

It doesn't recognize the OR, I want it always return JobId==0.

I tried uppercase, also tried parentheis where `((u.UserName == User.Identity.Name) OR (jL.JobId==0))`

Without the OR, it works fine, it is a syntax compiler error.

How on write a var query with combination condition AND/OR in Where Clause?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is C#, you need to use C# syntax for OR, which is [|| (The Conditional OR operator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx):

```
 (u.UserName == User.Identity.Name || jL.JobId == 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to use the c# operators

- && for and
- || for or

eg.

```
var query = from uM in db.aspnet_Memberships
            join uD in db.UserDetails
            on uM.UserId equals uD.UserId
            join jL in db.JobLists
            on uM.UserId equals jL.UserId
            where (u.UserName == User.Identity.Name || jL.JobId==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal AND (`&`/`&&`) and OR (`|`/`||`) operators of the C# language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use || instead of or.

((u.UserName == User.Identity.Name) || (jL.JobId==0))

I'm not sure how you will get a jobId though as it looks like you are wanting to do a left join. If the user does not exist in the jobLists table, then it will be null for jL.jobId and not return anything.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) for more on left joins